# Why my clock cannot be stopped for a second time-Why clearInterval does not work for a second timel(javascript)

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I just started learning coding with Javascript from scratch.
I have been trying to make a clock which can be stopped and started onclick.
I encountered a problem that really puzzles me:
When I click the "stop" button for the first time, the time does stop. 
When I click the "start" button, the clock runs again.
The problem is :

- When I click the "stop" button for the second time, the clock would
  not    stop.

Could you please kindly tell me why this happens?

```js
var myclock = setInterval("showtime()", 1000);

function start() {
  var myclock = setInterval("showtime()", 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(myclock);
}

function showtime() {
  var time_now = new Date();
  var local_time = time_now.toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = local_time;
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()">
```

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, copy and paste your code directly into the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1, `w` and `r` work with the same variable (same name and same location in memory) :

```
var x = 1;
function w () {
  x = 2;
}
function r () {
  return x;
}
w();
r(); // 2
```

Case 2, `w` and `r` work with different variables (same name but different locations in memory) :

```
var x = 1;
function w () {
  var x = 2;
}
function r () {
  return x;
}
w();
r(); // 1
```

In case 2, the `var` keyword creates a new variable that is local to `w`, while `r` keeps reading the old global variable. The same applies to your code. Because of the `var` keyword, `start` writes to a new local variable, while `stop` reads the old global variable. Remove `var` from `start` in order to update the global variable :

```
function start() {
  myclock = setInterval("showtime()", 1000);
}
```

Here is a fixed and slightly improved version of your code snippet :

```js
var myclock;

start();

function start() {
  showtime();
  myclock = setInterval(showtime, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(myclock);
}

function showtime() {
  var time_now = new Date();
  var local_time = time_now.toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = local_time;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()">
<span id="time"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `start` function:

```
var myclock = setInterval(...
```

You're defining a new variable here, that isn't available to `stop`. In order for it to work the way you intended, remove the `var`:

```
myclock = setInterval(...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're declaring the variable `myclock` again within your `start` function. When you refer `myclock` in `stop` you're referencing the variable outside, not the one within `start`. This means clearing does not clear the timer set in `start`.

Second, you're recreating the timer each time you click on `start` without clearing the previous one.

The fixed code would look something like this:

```js
function showTime() {
  var timeNow = Date();
  var localTime = timeNow.toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = localTime;
}

var myClock;

function stop() {
  clearInterval(myClock);
  myClock = null;
}

function start() {
  if (myClock)
    return; // timer is already set. no need to recreate.
    
  myClock = setInterval(showTime, 1000);
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start()" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)